# Looping in array to combine jsonb

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql, loops, for-loop

I'm unable to loop multiple array and construct it into jsonb.

```
CREATE TABLE emr.azt_macres (
    id serial NOT NULL,
    analyzer_test_full_desc varchar(50) NULL,
    specimen_id varchar(100) NULL,
    data_reading varchar(20) NULL,
    data_result varchar(20) NULL,
    result_status varchar(20) NULL,
    analyzer_message text NULL,
    test_result jsonb NULL,
    CONSTRAINT azt_macres_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

The array look like this. Bare in mind there are two Sample in array which is Sample123 and Sample456

```
1H|*^&|||Mindry^^|||||||PR|1394-97|20210225142532
P|3||QC1||^^||^^|U||||||||||||||||||||||||||
O|3|1^Sample123^1||TBILV^Bilirubin Total (VOX Method)^^
R|23|KA^Bilirubin Total (VOX Method)^^F|17.648074^^^^|µmol/L|
R|24|ATU^Alanine Aminotransferase^^F|58.934098^^^^|U/L|
L|1|N
1H|*^&|||Mindry^^|||||||PR|1394-97|20210225142532
P|3||QC1||^^||^^|U||||||||||||||||||||||||||
O|3|1^Sample456^1||TBILV^Bilirubin Total (VOX Method)
R|23|TBILV^Bilirubin Total (VOX Method)^^F|17.648074^^^^|
R|24|ALT^Alanine Aminotransferase^^F|58.934098^^^^|U/L|
R|25|TTU^Alkaline phosphatase^^F|92.675340^^^^|U/L|^|N||
```

I'm able to insert if there are only 1 sample barcode, however the second sample_id is not insert. Do I need to loop the array again?

my code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION emr.azintin(v_msgar)
 RETURNS jsonb
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
DECLARE
    v_cnt       INT = 0;
    v_msgar     text[];
    v_msgln     text;
    v_msgtyp    character varying(3);
    v_tmp       text;
    macres      azt_macres%rowtype;

BEGIN   

            macres.analyzer_test_full_desc := 'CHEMO';
        
            SELECT  split_part(items[3], '^', 2)
                  INTO macres.specimen_id
                FROM (
                  SELECT string_to_array(element, '|') as items
                 FROM unnest(v_msgar) as t(element)) t   
            WHERE items[1] = 'O';
        

            SELECT jsonb_agg(jsonb_build_object('resultId', split_part(items[3],'^',1),'resultValue',split_part(items[4],'^',1)))
               INTO macres.test_result
               FROM (
                  SELECT string_to_array(element, '|') as items
                 FROM unnest(v_msgar) as t(element)) t   
            WHERE items[1] = 'R';
   
        
              v_cnt := v_cnt + 1;

        
                    BEGIN
                        INSERT INTO azt_macres(analyzer_test_full_desc, specimen_id, data_reading ,
                            data_result,result_status,analyzer_message,test_result)
                            VALUES (macres.analyzer_test_full_desc, macres.specimen_id,macres.data_reading,
                                macres.data_result,macres.result_status,macres.analyzer_message, macres.test_result);
                    END;
END
$function$
;
```

Currently my output is like this

| specimen_id | test_result |
| --- | --- |
| sample123 | [{"resultId": "KA", "resultValue": "17.648074"}, {"resultId": "ATU", "resultValue":"58.934098"}, {"resultId": "TBILV", "resultValue": "17.648074"}, {"resultId": "ALT","resultValue": "58.934098"}, {"resultId": "TTU", "resultValue": "92.675340"}] |

supposely my output should be like this

| specimen_id | test_result |
| --- | --- |
| sample123 | [{"resultId": "KA", "resultValue": "17.648074"}, {"resultId": "ATU","resultValue":"58.934098"}] |
| sample456 | [{"resultId": "TBILV", "resultValue": "17.648074"}, {"resultId": "ALT","resultValue": "58.934098"}, {"resultId": "TTU", "resultValue": "92.675340"}] |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. Creating the output:**

As I see it, you need a group of the `R` elements by the previous `O` elements. That needs to create a group of connected `R` elements, which share the same `O` value:

[step-by-step demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=7518fb51b25787d4237da50070d17540)

Don't be afraid, it looks heavier than it is ;) To understand all described intermediate steps, please have a look at the fiddle where every step is executed separately to demonstrate its impact.

```
SELECT
    specimen_id,
    json_agg(result) as test_result                                             -- 9
FROM (
    SELECT
        code,
        first_value(                                                            -- 5
            split_part(id, '^', 2)
        ) OVER (PARTITION BY group_id ORDER BY index) as specimen_id,
        json_build_object(                                                      -- 7
            'result_id',
            split_part(id, '^', 1),                                             -- 6
            'result_value',
            split_part(value, '^', 1)
        ) as result
    FROM (
        SELECT
            parts[1] as code,
            parts[3] as id,
            parts[4] as value,
            elem.index,
            SUM((parts[1] = 'O')::int) OVER (ORDER BY elem.index) as group_id   -- 4
        FROM mytable t,
            unnest(myarray) WITH ORDINALITY as elem(value, index),              -- 1
            regexp_split_to_array(elem.value, '\|') as parts                    -- 2
       WHERE parts[1] IN ('R', 'O')                                             -- 3
    ) s
) s
WHERE code = 'R'                                                                -- 8
GROUP BY specimen_id
```

1. Put all array elements into separate records. `WITH ORDINALITY` adds an index to the records which represents the original position of the element in the original array.
2. Split the array elements into their parts (delimited by `|` character)
3. Filter only the `R` and `O` elements.
4. This is the most interesting part: Creating the group of connected records. The idea: Every `O` records gets a value `1` (boolean `true` cast into `int` is `1`, so: `(parts[1] = 'O')::int`), every `R` gets a `0` value. The cumulative [`SUM()` window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.htm) creates a total sum of the current and every previous record. So every `O` increases the sum value, the `R` values (add `0`) keep this value. So this generates the same group identifier for every `O` record and all directly following `R` records. To ensure the correct record order, we use the index, which was created by the `WITH ORDINALITY` in step 1.
5. The `first_value()` window function gives the first value of a group (= partition), in this case, it adds to every record the first value of the recently created group. This finally associates the `O` value with each related `R` record.
6. `split_part()` for retrieving the correct values from the strings
7. build your JSON object for every record
8. Remove the `O` records
9. Group by the `specimen_id` (which was added in step 5) and aggregate the result values into an array

Now we have the expected output

**2. Inserting:**

Insert is easy: You can take the result (maybe you need some columns more, just add them to the SELECT statement, we recently created and execute the INSERT statement:

```
INSERT INTO mytable (col1, col2) 
SELECT -- <query from above>
```

**3. Create function:**

Here it is not clear to me, what you want to achieve. Do you want to give the array as input parameter, or do you want to query a table? Why are you using a JSON return type although nothing is returned, ...

However, of course, you can put all the stuff into a stored procedure. Here I assume you give the array as input parameter into the procedure (for example, see [the answer to your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66364274/3984221)):

```
CREATE FUNCTION my_function(myarray text[]) RETURNS void AS $$
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO ...
    SELECT ...
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: you did somehow give me an  idea, but your step somehow inserting it the data in the table on the first place. i need to pass the array as parameter in my stored procedure

Comment: I manage up until point no 8 actually, but donno how to make it as no 9, to combine the jsonb an group it by specimen_id